# Histogram bar hiding tics

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I'm plotting a histogram in `gnuplot` and the bars end up covering the tics in the x axis, like so:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for sure if this will work or not, but you can try this:

```
 set grid noxtics noytics noztics front
```

From reading the documentation, it looks like that will push the tics to the top of the stack of objects when plotting (i.e. they'll get plotted after the bars making them visible *(I think)*).  Another option is to use transparency in your fillstyle, but that may not work depending on your terminal (and it may not be desirable).

Comment: I'm glad :).  I've been watching this answer to see if it worked (I was a little nervous posting it because I was too lazy to write a test myself, and while really good, gnuplot's documentation is not error free)

Answer (score 1):

You can add some lines to your script like

```
plot 'data.dat' # whatever your plot command is
set yrange [0:GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX*1.05]
replot
```

This extends the y range above the highest data point just a bit.  To find out the highest y point you have to plot once, then plot again after setting the y range.  Another option would be to do

```
set xtics out
```

This makes the xtics point out instead of in.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I need. I need a way to tell `gnuplot` to plot the tics **over** the bars and not the other way around.

Comment: Also, gnuplot 4.6 provides the `stats` command so that you don't even have to plot once to get `GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX` -- Which is convenient when working with other terminals (you don't need to `set term push` and `set term pop` anymore :^).