# gnuplot - Filledcurve issues

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following `gnuplot` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot << EOF

set term postscript portrait color enhanced 
set output 'temp.ps'
set border lw 0.2
unset key

set size 1,1
set origin 0,0
set size ratio 1
set size 0.47,0.47
set mxtics 2; set mytics 4

f(x,z)=z+5-5*log10(x)
set style fill transparent solid 0.1

set yrange [12:-2]; set xrange[0:10000]
plot f(x,17.55) w filledcurve lc rgb "black", \
f(x,17.5) w lines lt 2 lc rgb "green"

EOF
```

Which gives me an output like this:

[image: filledcurve]

I need two fix two things in this image:

1- the filled zone has a black line which delimitates it and this should go away

2- the filling is covering the x and y tics and this should not happen

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address 1):

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.1 noborder
```

To address 2):

```
set grid noxtics nomxtics noytics nomytics front
```

As a side note, `transparent` in your `set style fill` command does nothing in the postscript terminal as it doesn't support solid transparency.

Comment: Perfect! I got the answer to 2- from another question of mine answered by you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253438/histogram-bar-hiding-tics
You can add that line to your current answer and I'll mark the question as fully answered. Thanks again mgilson!

Comment: Well, you did it while I wrote my comment. You are fast!

Comment: @Gabriel -- I knew I had done it before (I didn't remember where), but it wasn't too hard to track down the second time :).